# Can you say "take a bite" to your son when you give a spoon of soup or pancake to him?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]
You spoon-fed your son by spooning some soup or a piece of pancake into his mouth.

When while holding the spoon in front of him, is it correct to say "**Yum! Yum! Take a bite**"?

I don't understand why some native speakers decide to say like that because the boy didn't **bite a piece from a large piece**.

I think the correct way is to say "**take a spoon / a spoonful of soup / a piece of pancake**". But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this noun meaning of "bite".
[Merriam-Webster "bite" noun 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bite)

noun 2: food: such as
a : the amount of food taken at a bite : morsel *couldn't eat another bite*
b : a small amount of food : snack  *have a bite to eat*

So, "take/have a bite" can mean to eat a small amount of food.

For soup, "bite" is less likely.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the context of feeding a small child, it would not be inappropriate at all to use a small, simply understood word like bite. If in the context of offering food to an adult you use the term, you can generally assume that a table fork or spoon will only contain enough quantity of a food to be considered a bite. So, in essence, you are not suggesting the recipient take a portion of the amount that you have offered on the spoon/fork/spork. You are offering them the entire contents of the eating utensil. Which is only a bite-sized portion of your whole meal.